# Textbox auto filling by another application..[Keygen]

Tags: winforms, mfc

I have seen the serial key field[Textbox] of a game which gets filled automatically when you launch keygen for that game which is an independent application. Here the key in the keygen textbox gets copied to the game's serial key field. How to achieve that kind of functionality in windows forms??

Comment: So is this Windows Forms or MFC? Or are you hosting a Windows Form in an MFC application? And please, if you absolutely must provide an example, don't use one that contains the words *game* and *keygen*.

Comment: Anything is Fine.. But i need that functionality